# Android: I need help passing a double value from one view to another view

Tags: java, android, android-intent

im trying to create a restaurant menu app that allows you to select different foods and a drink amount and when you click the button "total" it'll go to a second view to display: "your total is: _____". But I'm getting a ton of errors. If someone could help me out i'd appreciate it. I'm very new to this so some code I've stitched together from other answers from other questions on this site. Thank you!

Main activity view:

```
    package name.restaurantmenu2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

double totalPrice = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CheckBox pizzaCB  = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_pizza);

    if(pizzaCB.isChecked()){
        pizzaCB.toggle();
    }

    CheckBox burgerCB  = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_hamburger);

    if(burgerCB.isChecked()){
        burgerCB.toggle();
    }

    CheckBox hotdogCB  = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_hotdog);

    if(hotdogCB.isChecked()){
        hotdogCB.toggle();
    }

    CheckBox sodaCB  = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_soda);

    if(sodaCB.isChecked()){
        sodaCB.toggle();
    }
}

public void addSelected(View view){


    String multiple;

    CheckBox pizzaCB = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_pizza);
    CheckBox burgerCB = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_hamburger);
    CheckBox hotdogCB = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_hotdog);
    CheckBox sodaCB = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_soda);
    TextView pizzaTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_pizzaPrice);
    TextView burgerTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_hamburgerPrice);
    TextView hotdogTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_hotdogPrice);
    TextView sodaTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_sodaPrice);
    Spinner pizzaQty = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_pizzaQuantity);
    Spinner burgerQty = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_hamburgerQuantity);
    Spinner hotdogQty = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_hotdogQuantity);
    Spinner sodaQty = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_drinks);


    if(pizzaCB.isChecked()) {
        String value = pizzaTV.getText().toString();
        value = value.replace('$', ' ');
        multiple = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(pizzaQty.getSelectedItem().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(value));
        totalPrice++;
    }
    if(burgerCB.isChecked()) {
        String value = burgerTV.getText().toString();
        value = value.replace('$', ' ');
        multiple = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(burgerQty.getSelectedItem().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(value));
        totalPrice++;
    }
    if(hotdogCB.isChecked()) {
        String value = hotdogTV.getText().toString();
        value = value.replace('$', ' ');
        multiple = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(hotdogQty.getSelectedItem().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(value));
        totalPrice++;
    }
    if(sodaCB.isChecked()) {
        String value = sodaTV.getText().toString();
        value = value.replace('$', ' ');
        multiple = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(sodaQty.getSelectedItem().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(value));
        totalPrice++;
    }



}
public void onTotalClick(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ComputedActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble(totalPrice, double);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

View 2

```
package name.restaurantmenu2;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ComputedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Nothing to display";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_computed2);


}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void displayPrice(double number){

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    double result = b.getDouble(totalPrice);

    TextView priceTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_totalPrice);
    priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));

}



}
```

Comment: What is the first error?

Comment: what is the error? please paste the log cat

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your using the `bundle.putDouble(String name, double value)` method wrong. It should be `bundle.putDouble("NameOfYourDouble", actualDouble)`

```
double myDouble = 10.5;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("MyDouble", myDouble);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double myDouble = intent.getDoubleExtra("MyDouble", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When parsing double to string exception might occur in the addSelected() when parsing with an empty space in the string while replacing the $ with ' '.  Try to handle theexception